# super keyword without extends to the super class

Tags: java, superclass, super

There is a code of simple program. In constructor, `super()` is called without extends to the super class, I can not understand what will does this in this situation?

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int rollNum;

    Student(String name,int rollNum){
        super(); //I can not understand why super keyword here.
        this.name=name;
        this.rollNum=rollNum;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student s1 = new Student("A",1);
        Student s2 = new Student("A",1);

        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every class that doesn't explicitly extend another class implicitly extends `java.lang.Object`. So `super()` simply calls the no-arg constructor of Object.

Note that this explicit call is unnecessary since the compiler would add it for you. You only need to add a `super()` call in a constructor when you want to invoke a superclass constructor with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

> There is not need to add `super()` because it is by default added.

**It will call `Object` class's default constructor because in JAVA every class extends `Object` by default.**

Answer (score 0):

Constructor from your code works the same as:

```
Student(String name, int rollNum){
    this.name = name;
    this.rollNum = rollNum;
}
```

In your question `super()` is just calling constructor of `Object` class.