# Java. Super call in class which extends Object

Tags: java, super

I often see the code like this:

```
class MyClass{
      private int a;
      public MyClass(int a){
           super();        //what is the purpose of this method call?
           this.a = a;
      }
      //other class methods here
}
```

If class extends object, super() call invokes Object constructor which, as I know, does nothing. Then why it's needed to call super()? I'm interested in that particular case, when super() does nothing because it just calls Object().

Comment: I hope you understand, the call to `super()` is optional. Good practice, but if it doesn't serve any purpose to you, you can skip it.

Comment: Tastes differ. FWIW, my personal style is I write an explicit super call to remind myself and the reader that a super constructor is called, *except* if the super class is `Object` since I believe everyone knows the `Object()` constructor is eventually called and I don’t think a reminder about this fact is worth it.

Comment: @OleV.V. As it is redundant I would expect an experienced programmer to be puzzled why the call is there. Do you add a comment too?

Comment: Hahaha, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I liked that. No, I add no comment when calling `super()`.

Comment: @OleV.V. In that case, if I was to peer review your code I would ask you to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend reading the source - [documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)
Then a quote of [jb-nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441508/4723795):

> Note that this explicit call is unnecessary since the compiler would add it for you. You only need to add a super() call in a constructor when you want to invoke a superclass constructor with arguments.

In Java, `super` refers to the parent class. We can use it in two ways:

`super()` is calling the constructor of the parent class. `super.toString()` will call the parent class' implementation of `toString` method.

In your example:

```
class MyClass{
      private int a;
      public MyClass(int a){
           super();        //what purpose of this?
           this.a = a;
      }
      //other class methods here
}
```

it's calling the constructor of `Object` which is blank, so it's just being pedantic, but if we modify it:

```
class Foo extends Bar{
      private int a;
      public Foo(int a){
           super();        //what purpose of this?
           this.a = a;
      }
      //other class methods here
}
```

it stands for calling `Bar`'s constructor first.

Another usage which I have earlier described is:

```
class Bar {
    public String toString() {
        return "bar";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar{
      String foo = "foo";
      public Foo(){
           super();        //what purpose of this?
      }
      public String toString() {
          super.toString()
}
```

will result in returning "bar".