# understanding super keyword when no extends

Tags: java, super

```
public class B {
    B()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

I want to know what is happening in this program it is working fine but there i didnt extended any class

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html: Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. **Every class has Object as a superclass.**

Comment: every Class by default extended from Object class in Java nd the super() will call the constructor of Object class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [super keyword without extends to the super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441481/super-keyword-without-extends-to-the-super-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Class by default extended from `Object` class in Java and calling the `super()` will call the constructor of `Object` class.

Answer (score 2):

Every class extends `Object` - so you're invoking that `super()` method.  You can see this if you just set a breakpoint in the constructor and step into the super call.  Really what you have is :

```
public class B extends Object {
    B()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: if we extended a class then that mean it is extending both objct class and the class that we extended is that correct ? correct me if it is wrong thank you

Comment: It means your class is extending a class that extends Object.